# Can I get values from hidden field doing something as below?

Tags: javascript, jsp, stripes

I have a table with rows. I have to get the row values. I am putting the row values in an array through JavaScript and then on submitting the form I am iterating the array and appending the vales to a hidden input text. The text input is mapped to my action class. Can I get the values, or my approach is wrong. I am facing some issues.

```
$.each(productList, function(idx, val) {
$('#hiddenField').append(val);
});
```

where hiddenField is property that I have mapped in my action class. Now can I get this input's value? Does append() append all the values of the list?

Comment: Why are you asking us instead of testing it first

Comment: I tested and it did not work.So I asked. Had it worked, I would not have taken the pain of asking the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(productList, function(idx, val) {
   var hidden = $('input[name="yourHiddenName"]');
   hidden.val(hidden.val()+val));
});
```

Comment: Will this append to existing ones? - "hidden.val()+val"

Answer (score 0):

You will get the null value in Java calling request.getParameter("yourHiddenField") however if you use the submit button, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

"#hiddenField" points to an "id" of a HTML element and not to the "name" attribute which is used to get values on server side after submitting a form.

Maybe you should use "'[name=hiddenField]'" instead.